# Pass session from profile to new page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know how to pass session from login page to user's profile but how to pass the same session from profile to new page.

Comment: show some code what you tried ??

Comment: how to show code if i do not have idea how it works. I need idea first and then will code it

Comment: What? Session is across pages.

Comment: it doesn't need to pass session,you should call session by its specific name in any page you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of session.
Session exist in the server side of your application.
You can invoke your session in any controller's action like you said eg. user's profile.

```
public ActionResult YourNewAction(){
   var sessionModel = (CustomClass)HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"];

  //...
}
```

If you want to get user credentials it's event easier. You can invoke:

```
var identity = HttpContext.Current.User;
```

If you're storing eg. CustomClass in session ,above code is ugly. In this case you can create Custom Binder, please read: [ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)
and then:

```
public ActionResult YourNewAction(CustomClass sessionClass){
   //sessionClass will be automapped
}
```

I hope that i answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, session variables are stored in the web server’s memory. You can receive session value from any page after creating.
eg. from the login page if you redirect to any page, the code can be as follows:

```
protected void cmdRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Reading session value from Default.aspx:

```
string LoginUser ="";
if(Session["UserName"]!=null)
    LoginUser = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

Also, you can use the Membership class to get variables from the membership profile

```
Session["MySessionDataVariable"] = Membership.GetUser().UserName
```